# CHHapticEngine not generating haptic feedback nor throws error?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios17, haptic-feedback

I am trying to generate haptic feedback in an `iOS` application. I am doing so by using [CoreHaptics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics).

My code to do this is as follows:

```
do {
        let engine = try CHHapticEngine()
        try engine.start()
        
        let hapticPattern = try CHHapticPattern(events: [
            CHHapticEvent(eventType: .hapticTransient, parameters: [
                CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticSharpness, value: 1.0),
                CHHapticEventParameter(parameterID: .hapticIntensity, value: 1.0)
            ], relativeTime: CHHapticTimeImmediate)
        ], parameters: [])
        
       let player = try engine.makePlayer(with: hapticPattern)
       try player.start(atTime: 0)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error starting engine: \(error)")
    }
```

However running this code both directly in the `viewDidLoad()` method and an `@IBAction` with a `UIButton` to trigger it, does not result in any haptics playing.

The code doesn't throw any error either. Not in the `catch` statement or anywhere else.

I'm testing this on an iPhone 15 Pro. Both with silent mode on and off.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `engine` and `player` are local variables so they go out of existence when the surrounding function finishes — which is before the haptic even has a chance to play. Lift them up so that each is a *property* of the surrounding view controller and thus gains long life.

Comment: For working code, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p655HapticFeedback/HapticFeedback/ViewController.swift.